# Why don't we just keep all dynamic memory in arrays?

Tags: c++, caching, optimization, memory, heap-memory

In C/C++, when you allocate dynamic memory, the OS gives you an unpredictable address to some distant region of memory.  If you allocate a lot of dynamic memory, and need to travel between it (for example, linked lists, trees), then you have to waste time waiting for the CPU to consult RAM, because, more than likely, the piece of memory you wanted wasn't close to the piece of memory you had.

Recently, for a project in one of my university courses, I had to implement a tree such that nodes could have any number of children, and I had to be able to merge nodes into single trees in constant time.  So, I had a bunch of internal Node objects with a bunch of pointers to surrounding nodes.

Because this was C++, it was fast, of course, but with the time and memory it was being tested on, it had just okay performance.

So, I decided to try implementing pointer replacements which would really be indices of static vectors, and a function to grow the vector when a new object was needed, and a stack of 'deleted' indices that could be re-used.  This way, everything would be close together in memory, and dereferences were less likely to result in cache misses.  Also, because I knew the tree would not be tested on the scale of gigabytes of data, I could restrict these indices to 32 bits, reducing the memory overhead of the tree structure significantly.

The results were amazing -- in most cases a third the time and memory of the staff implementation for my course.

My question is, if the cache benefits are so extreme, why do we bother directly using `new` and `delete` at all?  Why not just stick everything in vectors, one for each type?

Comment: Sure, if your program can predict in advance exactly how much it will need of every object, no matter what the program will end up doing, while it runs.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I meant dynamically allocated arrays

Comment: There are limitations of a vector such as insertion of a element at at the begining or middle of a vector which happens at O(n ) time complexity. It's the trade off you need to chose how often you insert and delete elements Vs how often you search a element. If u don't want to use new/delete you can go with std::map.

Comment: *which would really be indices of static vectors* -- Sounds like this would be an issue in a multi-threaded program without proper synchronization.

Comment: That is why we have allocators. Also, when the performance meets your need, the benefits of those performance boosts would be canceled by the cost of optimization.

Comment: @TruthSeeker, this is why new objects were only ever placed on the back of the vector.  If an object was 'deleted', this simply meant the index in the vector was pushed to a stack.  When new objects were created, the program would check the stack for free indices, and, if it found one, pop it off the top and overwrite the 'deleted' data.  There was no insertion anywhere but the back of the vector -- amortized constant time.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin I created a fully-templated abstract class that hid all of the complexity of the static vector.  It was essentially a drop-in replacement for the pointers in the original implementation.

Comment: @StuartBotfield Posting it to Code Review StackExchange would be a good idea if you would like to hear other's opinion about it.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin I can't post my code publicly; the automatic grader will scrape it, and flag my submission as plagiarism

Answer (score 3):

You use the standard allocators when they're "good enough" for what you need to do.  The difference between a program that runs in 10ms vs one that runs in 100ms may be 10x, but in practice that difference is meaningless.  Both run "instantly".

That's not to say you should never use your own allocation strategy.  In general, you should use an allocation strategy that matches your use-case and requirements.  What you've described sounds a lot like [object pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), which is a well-known and frequently used pattern in situations where you have lots of objects of the same type.

---

Keep in mind that the standard memory allocators have to support every possible use-case. 
 Since your special-purpose allocator is aware of your usage patterns, you're able to squeeze a bit more performance out of it *for your specific use-case*, but it's unlikely it would be faster than the heavily tuned standard allocators in general across all possible use-cases.

What most standard library implementations use for `new`/`malloc` is a pooling allocator, which is somewhat of a generalization of the object pool you've implemented.  The first time some memory is requested, they allocate a big chunk of memory from the OS and then hand out pieces of that pool as its requested, keeping track of which pieces are in use and which are available for later (re-)use.  When the pool runs out they'll get another chunk of memory from the OS and start handing out bits of that.

The biggest difference from what you've implemented is that when you allocate a new pool you move everything from the old one into the new one.  In the general case for large amounts of data that copying will likely become a bottleneck that would overcome any benefit you would get from locality and if your data is larger than a cache line it doesn't really matter if it's all contiguous or not.

Your approach also requires that every user of the allocator be aware of its implementation, since each re-allocation will invalidate any pointers or references to the old pool.  That means you've traded ease-of-maintenance for performance.  That may not matter for a school project that you'll never look at again, but for real-world applications ongoing maintenance cost is a very big consideration.

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't we just keep all dynamic memory in arrays?

To be fair, we do keep **most** of dynamic memory in arrays.

But sometimes an array cannot achieve the same asymptotic complexity as a node based structure can, and in such case it can be beneficial to not use the array.

> why do we bother directly using new and delete at all?

It is extremely rare to need to use new and delete directly.

Comment: I think the last time I used `new` was about 11 years ago.  And in hindsight, was probably a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Miles' very good answer:

Sure, there are many awesome tricks you can do if you write your own memory allocation mechanism tailored to your specific usage scenario. We usually do not bother with that, because the standard mechanism is good enough, and because we generally do not want to have to write and keep maintaining lots of middleware code, and because we do not want to confuse other people who might need to look at our code while being unfamiliar with our custom, quirky, arcane mechanisms of getting things done.

In a nutshell, we have come to the point where computers are so fast that ease-of-development and maintainability are more important than raw performance.

That having been said, in extreme applications where performance is indeed of paramount importance, people do indeed tend to roll their own mechanisms for things like memory allocation, like you did, in order to save every clock cycle that can be saved.

Furthermore, there are ways to implement your own memory allocation mechanism behind the scenes, so that your application-level code does not need to know that this mechanism is in place, and it does not have to look any different from code that does things the "normal" or "standard" way.

Did you know that the `new` and `delete` operators can be overloaded in C++?  Look it up, it will open up a whole new world for you.  So, you can write your pooling memory allocator in such a way that application-level code is making what appears to be perfectly normal (or near-perfectly-normal) use of `new` and `delete`, and you can intercept this usage behind the scenes and redirect it to your custom memory allocator.  I have done that stuff in the past, it is very interesting to say the least.